# Eclipse is opening up as Eclipse Juno and not as Android Development Tool

Tags: android, eclipse

I am a beginner in android,

I have downloaded JDK from  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
and
ADT Bundle from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

After this I have installed JDK then extracted ADT bundle to users folder.

After this when I am opening Eclipse from the eclipse folder its opening as eclipse juno and not as android development tool

I want to get Android development tool and not eclipse Juno. Can someone help me?

Comment: Why dont you using eclipse juno for developing android apps? It has "create new android app" option right?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: You are doing it right. You should open eclipse from the folder ADT that you have downloaded. Can you create new Android Application Project on eclipse?

Comment: http://techblogon.com/install-eclipse-android-sdk-adt-pluin/  how to install android sdk and creating a sample project.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need Android ADT (with eclipse) you can download from [32bit ADT](https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip) and [64Bit ADT](https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip)

Answer (score 0):

download and installing instructions for eclipse and Adt plugin from [here.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)